# AlphaBlend fails on one machine in one software

Tags: api, vb6

I am using the same AlphaBlend function as declared like this:

```
Public Declare Function AlphaBlend Lib "MSIMG32.dll" (ByVal hDCDest As Long, ByVal nXOriginDest As Long, ByVal nYOriginDest As Long, ByVal nWidthDest As Long, ByVal nHeightDest As Long, ByVal hDCSrc As Long, ByVal nXOriginSrc As Long, ByVal nYOriginSrc As Long, ByVal nWidthSrc As Long, ByVal nHeightSrc As Long, ByVal lBlendFunction As Long) As Long
```

There are some machines where my code works perfectly fine and does exactely what it should.

On one machine, the very same code works fine in application A, but the same code in application B makes AlphaBlend fail.

Imagine the following:
You have 2 identical twins both eating an apple. Both apples are perfectly the same.

One twin swallows it successfully, the other twin dies trying to do so.

GetLastError returns 0.

How could I investigate what goes wrong?

One some machines, all is fine.

On the one machine in question however, I have compiled the very same code running in two applications: Application A and application B.

In application A, AlphaBlend fails, and in application B, AlphaBlend succeeds.
And it's ALWAYS that it fails in application A.

I have even doubted VB6's sanity and checked if "Len" actually returns the correct length.

I use VB6 since 20 years, but I have never experienced something that crazy.

Does anybody have any idea why the same code might fail in that one application?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function AlphaBlend Lib "MSIMG32.dll" (ByVal hDCDest As Long, ByVal nXOriginDest As Long, ByVal nYOriginDest As Long, ByVal nWidthDest As Long, ByVal nHeightDest As Long, ByVal hDCSrc As Long, ByVal nXOriginSrc As Long, ByVal nYOriginSrc As Long, ByVal nWidthSrc As Long, ByVal nHeightSrc As Long, ByVal lBlendFunction As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "Kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare Function GetClientRect Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "USER32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long

Private Type BLENDFUNCTION
    BlendOp As Byte
    BlendFlags As Byte
    SourceConstantAlpha As Byte
    AlphaFormat As Byte
End Type

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Const AC_SRC_OVER = &H0

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    Dim lHwnd&
    lHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "twsseetechcamwin")
    
    If lHwnd = 0 Then
        Me.Caption = "is null!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Me.Caption = "ok"

    Dim LBF As Long
    Dim bf As BLENDFUNCTION

    With bf
        .BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER
        .SourceConstantAlpha = 255
    End With

    Dim lLen&
    lLen = Len(bf) 'just check for sanity... I wanted to make sure that it's 4, and it indeed is

    Call MoveMemory(LBF, bf, Len(bf)) 'Copy struct into a Long var

    Dim rOtherWin As RECT
    GetClientRect lHwnd, rOtherWin

    Dim lOtherDC&
    lOtherDC = GetDC(lHwnd)

    Dim r As RECT
    GetClientRect Me.hWnd, r

    Dim lret&
    lret = AlphaBlend(Me.hdc, 0, 0, (r.Right - r.Left), (r.Bottom - r.Top), lOtherDC, 0, 0, (rOtherWin.Right - rOtherWin.Left), (rOtherWin.Bottom - rOtherWin.Top), LBF)

    Dim lWinErr&
    lWinErr = GetLastError()
    
    Me.Caption = Time & " ret: " & lret & ", err: " & lWinErr&

    ReleaseDC lHwnd, lOtherDC

End Sub
```

Comment: According to docs `alphablend` doesn't set lasterror. And in VB6 we have `err.lastdllerror`, calling the API one will return the program's last error, probably VB6 runtime call.

Comment: All the potential causes are in the remarks section of the docs.

Comment: @user14797724 I guess you are referring to "An error occurs (and the function returns FALSE) if the source device context identifies an enhanced metafile device context.". Can you tell me what you suspect in my case?

Comment: I'm referring to all the potential failures - you need to verify each potential cause.

Comment: @user14797724 I have posted the answer. Just wanted to tell you because I guess you are interested in the cause, too.

Comment: My point was `GetLastError` has already been called by VB6 runtime and put into `err.lastdllerror`. When you call it you are testing a VB6 runtime call so should always be 0, else VB6 crashes.

Comment: i.e. `lWinErr = GetLastError()` -> `lWinErr = Err.LastDllError` makes more sense but will probably return 0 anyway.

Comment: Yes, both return 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs when the OS is set to high DPI settings (like display everything in 150%) AND if the application has a manifest that states `dpiaware=true`.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- Remove `dpiaware` from the manifest
- Add a manifest to the other process as well and declare `dpiaware=true` in that manifest, too. This way there is no discrepancy between the 2 processes. This of course only works if it's your product / process, and you have the possibility to compile it with a manifest.

Comment: Good find. Glad you solved your problem and this is likely to help others as well!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is machine-specific (assuming that is accurate) there is a possibility that the two programs A and B are not loading the same copy of MSIMG32.dll.

I would check: are there multiple copies of that DLL on the PC? Especially if there is a copy in the program folder for A or B?

Also you can run Process Monitor and observe the running program to see exactly what DLLs are being loaded. That could at least confirm they are both running the same DLL and eliminate that as a potential cause.

---

Other than that, personally I would throw in some debug logging and really verify that the inputs to the failing function are the same.

Comment: Both use the same DLL, residing in Windows/SysWow64/msimg32.dll